# EPPlus: Cannot open file when another person is blocking

Tags: excel, vb.net, epplus, file-access

I use the following code to open an excel-file:

```
Private EPXlApp As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage
Private EPXlFile As FileInfo
Private EPXlSheet As ExcelWorksheet
Private EPXlWorkbook As ExcelWorkbook

Public Sub New(newFilePath As String, Optional password As String = "")

PathFile = newFilePath

OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial
EPXlFile = New FileInfo(PathFile)
EPXlApp = New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(EPXlFile, password) ' ---> here the error occurs
EPXlWorkbook = EPXlApp.Workbook
EPXlSheet = EPXlApp.Workbook.Worksheets(1)

End sub
```

This works. But if one person block the file, i can't open it again. I don't understand the error message

System.IO.InvalidDataException: "File S:\Team\file.xlsm is not an encrypted package"

because thats the rigt password, it has already worked if no one blocked the excel file.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: "not an encrypted package" suggests that there is no password. Did you try it without the password parameter?

Comment: Yes, then i get the following error code:

Comment: System.IO.InvalidDataException: "The file is not an valid Package file. If the file is encrypted, please supply the password in the constructor."

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "if one person block the file"? Do you mean that if someone else has the file open at the same time then your code cannot open it?

Comment: Is it open in excel while you try to open in EPPLus?

Comment: yes exactly, someone else has the file open, because the file is located on a server.